# Prolog. Function call, add brackets to output

Tags: prolog

I have a predicate:

```
test(X, Test) :-
  Test =.. [integer,X].
```

When I call it I get:

```
?- test(1,Test).
Test = integer(1).
```

How can I add additional brackets to the output?

I expect it to look like this:

```
?- test(1,Test).
Test = (integer(1)).
```

Edit.
Found it easier to print everything with write/1.

Comment: You can print or have a string in that format, but terms cannot have redundant parenthesis. Try querying `Test = (integer(1)).`, you will see that the outer parentheses are removed.

Comment: What is your motivation to print it like this? It is relevant because the parentheses are meaningless when you write them like this, as @rajashekar said.

Comment: This predicate could have been written as `test(X, integer(X)).` no need for `=..`

Comment: Why do you call it a function?

Comment: @TA_intern I know that. I am trying to get the OP to understand that by trying to answer the question in the comment. If I had to make a list of what identifies a Prolog newbie that would be near the top of the list. It would real close to using a lower case `p` for Prolog. I am also hoping they will change the title. That is one of the biggest reasons I don't use SO is because more than not the titles are wrong.

Comment: Of interest: [Best practices for printing](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/best-practices-for-printing/4231)